# Postgres Subquery while inserting data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to run a query in which a particular column value is a foreign key.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test(group_id, test_name, test_code) VALUES (SELECT group_id FROM tbl_group
 where group_code = '6868' , 'test', '123');
```

This is my query. On executing this query i'm getting an error as

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: ... tbl_test(group_id, test_name, test_code) VALUES (SELECT group
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `values()`, you can just add the literals to the select's column list, like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test(group_id, test_name, test_code) 
SELECT group_id , 'test', '123'
FROM tbl_group
WHERE group_code = '6868'
  ;
```